# list component update while post new record from other component in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I am working on an Angular 7 project. i have two components one is add-role and list role. these two component elements put in other role component. when i am adding new record through add role component how can show new data in list role component with out any refresh?

Any help much appreciated...

**role.component.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <add-role></add-role>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <list-role></list-role>
            </div>
```

**add-role.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from '../../_services/users.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Role } from '../../_models/Role';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-role',
  templateUrl: './add-role.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-role.component.sass']
})
export class AddRoleComponent implements OnInit {
  public roleModel = {};
  roles: Role[] = [];
  constructor(private userService: UsersService, private toastr: ToastrService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onSubmit(roleForm: NgForm) {
    this.userService.addRole(this.roleModel).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.toastr.success(res.message, "Success!");
        roleForm.form.reset();
      },
      err => {
        this.toastr.error(err, "oops!");
      }
    )};


}
```

**list-role.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Role } from '../../_models/Role';
import { UsersService } from '../../_services/users.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-role',
  templateUrl: './list-role.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-role.component.sass']
})
export class ListRoleComponent implements OnInit {
  roles: Role[] = [];
  constructor(private userService: UsersService, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRoles();
  }
  getRoles(){
    this.userService.listroles().pipe(first()).subscribe(roles => {
      this.roles = roles;
    });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass roles from father componet to child `list-role`

#### Role Component HTML

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-
  <add-role (role)="roles.push($event)"></add-role>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-
  <list-role [roles]="roles"></list-role>
</div>
```

#### Role Component TS

In ts you should take the roles from the userService

```js
roles = [];

getRoles() { 
  this.userService.listroles().pipe(first()).subscribe(roles => {
    this.roles = roles;
  });
}
```

#### list-role.component.ts

Take the roles and merge with others

```js
@Input() set roles(roles: Roles[]) {
  this.roles = merge({}, roles);
};
```

#### Add Role

In add role you can emit the current role created

```js
@Ouput() role: EventEmitter<Role> = new EventEmitter<Role>();


onSubmit(roleForm: NgForm) {
    this.userService.addRole(this.roleModel).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.toastr.success(res.message, "Success!");
        roleForm.form.reset();
        this.role.emit(this.roleModel);
      },
      err => {
        this.toastr.error(err, "oops!");
      }
    )};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use the async pipe. You can the documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

You have three components, a father (RoleComponent) and two children(ListRoleComponent and AddRoleComponent).

It is best to issue an event from AddRoleComponent to RoleComponent to warn that a new role was inserted. Then you can ask for the roles again. My code is this:

**role.component.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <app-add-role (formSubmited)="onFormSubmited($event)"></app-add-role>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <app-list-role [roles]="(roles | async)?.roles"></app-list-role>
</div>
```

**role.component.ts**

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  roles: Observable<Role[]>;

  constructor(private userService: UsersService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRoles();
  }

  getRoles() {
    this.roles = this.userService.listRoles();
  }

  onFormSubmited(e) {
    this.getRoles();
  }

}
```

**list-role.component.html (Short version)**

```
<div style="color: red" *ngFor="let r of roles">
  {{ r.name }}
</div>
```

**list-role.component.ts**

```
export class ListRoleComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() roles: Role[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**add-role.component.html (Short version) **

```
<button (click)="onSubmit()">Adicionar</button>
```

**add-role.component.ts**

```
export class AddRoleComponent implements OnInit {
  public roleModel = {
    name: 'Nuevo'
  };
  roles: Role[] = [];

  @Output() formSubmited = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(private userService: UsersService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onSubmit(roleForm: NgForm) {
    this.userService.addRole(this.roleModel).subscribe(
      res => {
        // this.toastr.success(res.message, "Success!");
        // roleForm.form.reset();
        this.formSubmited.emit(true); // important
      },
      err => {
        // this.toastr.error(err, "oops!");
      }
    );
  }
}
```

In the service the method are:

```
  listroles(): Observable<Role[]> {
    return this.http.get<Role[]>(this.url);
  }

  addRole(roleModel): Observable<any> {
    const params = JSON.stringify(roleModel);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post<Role>(this.url + '/add', params, {headers});
  }
```

You can tell that I have added a single field to my model Role (name). You can continue your logic, this is just an example that I have recreated

Comment: i am getting empty list after form submitted.issue in role.component.ts i think.. pls  help me in that?

Comment: You can give us a better explanation?